# What is the equivalent to the powershell command Add-ADFSClient on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

Trying to figure out SSO.

We installed ADFS on our Windows Server 2012 then I  created an Azure Active Directory version of an SSO sample project following:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-client

**That worked fine.**

Then trying to port it to our Windows Server 2012 ADFS I followed this tutorial:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

Which at one point says to run the following powershell command to add the WPF windows client to ADFS:

```
Add-ADFSClient -Name “MyClient” -ClientId “E1CF1107-FF90-4228-93BF-26052DD2C714” -RedirectUri “http://anarbitraryreturnuri/”
```

But this tutorial is geared towards Windows Server 2012 **R2** and we run the plain Windows Server 2012 version and this Add-ADFSClient powershell command is missing.

How can I do the equivalent adding of a Windows client to ADFS on Windows Server 2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples and commands you are running are OAuth and there is no OAuth support in 2012 hence the lack of the PowerShell command.

2012 R2 supports OAuth authorization code grant only.

2016 (TP3)  has the full OpenID Connect / OAuth stack.

Comment: thanks @nzpcmad, we ended up upgrading to R2 and I can now proceed forward!